# Help with getting Netflix to work?

Tags: 12.04, netflix

I tried getting it to work through here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/01/how-to-watch-lovefilm-redbox-instant-or-netflix-on-ubuntu#content but nothing has worked! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Netflix only works in Linux through Wine or in a virtual machine like XP running in virtualbox. I have not found the experience to be worth the time spent watching. Perhaps if your system is fast enough, you'll have a different experience. There's a version in the Software Center if you'd like to try that.
[image]